# READ UNCOMMITTED をむしろ使いたい状況？

Tags: sql, mariadb

私のサーバーシステムでは READ UNCOMMITTED をむしろ使用したいような状況が発生致しました。
私の考えは正しいでしょうか？

掲示板アプリのサーバーにて、掲示板に投稿したとして以下の処理が発生します。

- トランザクション

  - トークテーブルに投稿を格納（insert）
  - 掲示板テーブルの　トータル投稿数更新（サブクエリではなくcount:=count+１で）　と　最終投稿時間を更新（update）
  - 掲示板テーブルから　トータル投稿数　をセレクト（select）
- このトランザクション実行後、３番めのSQLで取得した投稿数が１０００未満ならコミット
  そうではないならロールバック（投稿失敗）

要するに、投稿格納後に投稿数上限の１０００を超えていないかのチェックを行います。
一見、 SERIALIZABLE がいいように思えますが（もちろんそうなのですが）
処理性能のことも考えると、むしろここは一番最弱な READ UNCOMMITTED を使用したほうがいい気がしてきました。

READ UNCOMMITTED なら
２つの投稿トランザクションが同時に処理された場合、どちらかが先に２つめのSQLを実行した時点で、もう片方はトランザクション中に３番めのSQLにてそのコミットされていない値を取得して、
最大投稿数以上投稿してしまうことを防げると思ったからです。

この場合、上記の場合は

- ２つとも投稿処理が失敗する可能性（お互い、更新後にセレクトしたら）
  　→　そのぐらいべつにおｋ
- 最新投稿時間がもう片方の投稿の時間になる可能性（セレクト順だけ逆転する）
  　→　とは言えど、同時に発生した処理のためその差は数ミリ秒程度なのでおｋ
- 片方だけロールバック発生したらカウントがおかしくなることがある（現在インクリメント系　count=count+1なので）
  　→　重要な不具合なのですがそもそもこのカラムをなくし、毎回取得時にカウントすることにする

が発生するかと思われますが、それは妥協とします。
このようにあえて　READ UNCOMMITTED　の弱点を利用するってのはやめるべきでしょうか？

Comment: データベースエンジンを書いて頂けると良いと思います。

Comment: 失礼致しました　InnoDB　でございます
MariaDBの10.1です

Comment: mariadbに詳しくありませんが、`TRIGGER`で1000行を超える`INSERT`をエラーにするとかではダメですか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

データベースとは大量のデータを正確に扱うことを目的としています。

> - ２つとも投稿処理が失敗する可能性（お互い、更新後にセレクトしたら）
>     　→　そのぐらいべつにおｋ
> - 最新投稿時間がもう片方の投稿の時間になる可能性（セレクト順だけ逆転する）
>     　→　とは言えど、同時に発生した処理のためその差は数ミリ秒程度なのでおｋ

のように不正確でも構わないという条件ですと、`READ UNCOMMITTED`かどうかという議論の前提に立っていないと思います。というのも`READ UNCOMMITTED`においてもデータベースエンジンは正確性を保証するよう動作するからです。

---

> - トランザクション
>
>   - トークテーブルに投稿を格納（insert）
>   - 掲示板テーブルの　トータル投稿数更新（サブクエリではなくcount:=count+１で）　と　最終投稿時間を更新（update）
>   - 掲示板テーブルから　トータル投稿数　をセレクト（select）
> - このトランザクション実行後、３番めのSQLで取得した投稿数が１０００未満ならコミット
>     そうではないならロールバック（投稿失敗）

という動作を不正確でも構わないというのであれば、

- 投稿時

  - 投稿数が1000以上であればエラー
  - トークテーブルに投稿を格納（insert）
  - その他の更新
- 閲覧時

  - 先頭の1000行のみ取り出し

とでもすればトランザクション自体も必要なくなります。また、元の案のような`INSERT`後にロールバックするよりも、上記のようなそもそも不用意に`INSERT`を行わない方がデータベースへの負担は少ないはずです。

Comment: 上記については、READ UNCOMMITTEDでも　commit　されていない値を必ず読み込むとは保証されないということでしょうか？
READ UNCOMMITTEDのデメリットをメリットというか、仕様として使用するのはやめたほうがいいということでしょうか？

下記はそういう方法もありですね
そちらで進めてみたいと思います

Answer (score 7):

> READ UNCOMMITTED なら
>   ２つの投稿トランザクションが同時に処理された場合、どちらかが先に２つめのSQLを実行した時点で、もう片方はトランザクション中に３番めのSQLにてそのコミットされていない値を取得して、
>   最大投稿数以上投稿してしまうことを防げると思ったからです。

この前提は誤りです。

READ UNCOMMITTEDは「他のトランザクションによって変更されCOMMITされていないデータを**読む可能性がある**」のであって、「COMMITされていないデータを**必ず読む**」ではないのです。

999件のデータが登録された状態で2つのトランザクションが同時に走ったときに、

> 掲示板テーブルの　トータル投稿数更新（サブクエリではなくcount:=count+１で）　と　最終投稿時間を更新（update）

・想定通り999+1、1000+1となる
・両方のトランザクションが999+1を行う

のどちらになるかはわかりません。

Comment: なるほどです！
重要な意見ありがとうございます

保証されないのですね
危ないところでした…